# CSS - Float Left makes Div disappear

Tags: css, wordpress

Using Divi in Wordpress.

I have 2 (among many) blog posts, one built without the Divi Builder(earlier on), the other built with Divi Builder.

This one was built without the Divi Builder and works nicely. I set float:left on article div.et_post_meta_wrapper and it looks as I want, with the Text wrapping around the image.
[Working Post](https://www.staging6.reekooz.com/explaining-adhd-to-your-child/)

This one, with the exact same CSS but was built with the Divi Builder, when I turn on float:left, it makes the entire Div disappear.
[Broken Post](https://www.staging6.reekooz.com/why-was-vayarin-discontinued/)

Can someone find the problem for me?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I explained the problem, when I do float left the entire div disappears. I have tried looking through and adjusting css where I could.  This is a WordPress page. Do you expect me to post the entire css of the page?

Comment: Yes, we expect you post a [mcve] for the reasons in my original comment.